# Cannot get the Apache Jena parser to pick up the @id from a json-ld file

Tags: jena, json-ld

I have a jsonld file that I am parsing using Jena. The file has @type @id  "rdfs:label" and  "rdfs:comment" and also ranges and domains. I have code like this

```
   Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

        Reader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
        Model model = m.read(fileReader, null, "JSON-LD");
        StmtIterator it = model.listStatements();
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

        System.out.println("Labels");
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Statement statement = it.next();
  ....
```

It seems to pick up all the content but does not see the @id statements. How do I pick up the @id statements  in this parser?

A fragment of the json-ld is

```
         "@id": "aaa:bbb",
         "@type": [
            "rdfs:Class",
            "owl:Class"
         ],
         "rdfs:label": {
            "@language": "en",
            "@value": "cccc"
         },
         "rdfs:comment": {
            "@language": "en",
            "@value": "dddd."
         },
         "rdfs:member": [
            {
               "@id": "aaaa:eeee"
            },
            {
               "@id": "aaaa:fffff"
            }
         ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it out. It the @id can be accessed in the getLocalName() methods on the subject or the resources.